# R Solving large sparse non-square matrices

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, linear-regression, matrix-inverse, flare

I'm trying to solve a large sparse matrix linear regression problem. I have created two matrices as follows:

```
> dim(A)
[1] 26573 32991

> dim(B)
[1] 26573     1
```

If i use matrixmodels lm.fit.sparse, i get the following error:

```
> X=MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse(A,B)
Error in .solve.dgC.qr(if (cld@className %in% c("dtCMatrix", "dgCMatrix")) x else as(x,  : dgCMatrix_qrsol(<26573 x 32991>-matrix) requires a 'tall' rectangular matrix
```

What does requires a tall matrix mean? If i change B so that it's a sparse matrix:

```
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
```

and try to solve again, i get a different error:

```
> X=MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse(A,B)
Error: is.numeric(y) is not TRUE
```

Does anyone know the best way to go about solving this problem?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have more columns than rows. Thus, you matrix in not "tall" but "wide" and does not have full rank. The `lm.fit.sparse` function uses either `.solve.dgC.chol` or `.solve.dgC.qr` from the `Matrix` package. You can have a further look at `?Matrix::solve`.

You need to use a regularization method instead or method use pseudo inverse to solve the problem (I would highly recommend the former). It seems neither are available in the `MatrixModels` package though I may be wrong.

Comment: I have found the 'flare' package and used:

Comment: I have found the 'flare' package and used: `library(flare)
# SQRT Lasso
out = slim(A,B,method="lq",nlambda=40,lambda.min.value=sqrt(log(200)/120))
` but i have no idea what it is doing? does anyone know if this is correct? It returned an error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.2 Gb`

Comment: I have never used the `flare` package but it seems like you hit a memory limit. See `help("Memory-limits")`. If you problem is sparse (as in many zero entries of your matrix) then check the `glmnet` package. It seems like it can handle big problems -- se [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302893/how-does-glmnet-handle-larger-datasets).